# Docker-Compose: /entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, entry-point

I'm trying to build a compose file with Django services with an entrypoint for each service to perform migrations, but docker can't locate the entrypoint.sh when I mount my directory, but it works when I don't.

the container shows this error

```
exec /code/dev/entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory
```

dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.11-slim-bullseye

WORKDIR /code


COPY req.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r req.txt --no-cache-dir



COPY ./dev/entrypoint.sh ./dev/
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' ./dev/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x ./dev/entrypoint.sh
# Convert line endings to Unix-style (LF)
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dos2unix && dos2unix ./dev/entrypoint.sh && chmod +x ./dev/entrypoint.sh

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["/code/dev/entrypoint.sh"]


CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

compose.yaml

```
services:

  auth:
    build:
      context: ./Auth
      dockerfile: dev/dockerfile
    container_name: Auth
    env_file:
      - "./Auth/Auth/.env"
    ports:
      - 8001:8000
    expose:
      - 8001
    networks:
      - backend

    volumes:
      - ./Auth:/code

  artifact:
    build:
      context: ./Artifact
      dockerfile: dev/dockerfile
    container_name: Artifact
    env_file:
      - "./Artifact/Artifact/.env"
    ports:
      - 8002:8000
    expose:
      - 8002
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./Artifact:/code


networks:
  backend:
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
# entrypoint.sh
python manage.py makemigrations
# Run migrations
python manage.py migrate

# Then run the main container command (passed to us as arguments)
exec "$@"
```

directory structure inside docker:

[image]

Comment: @Mate didn't work.

Comment: The `volumes:` block hides any setup the Dockerfile does (for example changing the line endings in the entrypoint script) and you should delete it.  The code is already built into the image and you don't need to separately inject it.

Comment: @DavidMaze Still that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: The error you get is weird: why is it talking about `/point.sh` and not `entrypoint.sh` ?

Comment: oh my bad,  locally i call it point.sh but i changed it when i asked the question so it can be readable, i will update it now.

Comment: @DavidMaze Mounting a volume can be useful for local development and hot reloading though.